# hp Stylus disables touchscreen

Tags: kubuntu, hp, touchscreen, stylus

I have kubuntu 20.04 LTS on HP Pavillion 360. My touchscreen often stops working while editing with HP provided stylus on **Xournal** or **Stylus Lab Write** along with the disabling of right click of mouse on desktop.

I can restore them by simply piping commands that enable them via xinput, but still is a nuisance.

My question is why a stylus that works on a digitizer screen disables basic touch screen function and right click of mouse, which breaks the workflow.

Comment: Could you check whether it works better in 21.10?